# Initial local git repo won't stage all files

Tags: git

I'm having trouble setting up my local machine to push to a vps. I've done this numerous times without issue, but can't seem to get this particular one working.

I've initialized a fresh repo, do the standard git add .

Every time I run git add or git commit I get this message:

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
#
#   modified:   wp-content/themes/royalcoffeebar (modified content, untracked content)
```

The problem is, I can't get the unstaged files to stage. I'm confused as to why it's saying the content is modified when it's the initial commit. I've also tried removing the repo and starting again, but get the same results.

I've tried git --force and git add -A .   None of which works.

This is my .gitignore file - http://pastebin.com/PFh9CQ9M

Dev environment - 13" mbp with mavericks.

Comment: What is the contents of `wp-content/themes/royalcoffeebar`?  Is there any chance that this is a directory that is itself a git repository (i.e., does it contain a `.git` directory)?

Comment: That was the exact issue. Thanks for that @larsks